# AngularJS , REST, C# Service, 405 - Post Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, angularjs, rest, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to do a full Angularjs web site for training. I've read many articles about this *Method not allowed*, but didn't find a solution. I'm trying to send a data object to my service.

> Error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Here is my AngularJS Part.

```
var addNews =
        {
            Title: newsList.newsTitle,
            NewsContent: newsList.newsContent,
            CreationDate: newsList.newsCreationDate,
            CreatedBy: newsList.newsAuthor,
            ModificationDate: newsList.newsCreationDate,
            ModifiedBy: newsList.newsAuthor
        };

    var news = JSON.stringify(addNews);


    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://localhost:11672/InfinytecServices.svc/SaveNews',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        data: news
    });
```

Here's my service part

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "/SaveNews",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    int SaveNews(News news);
```

WebConfig Comming

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>

    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add
          name="crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior"
          type="InfinytecWebService.CORSEnablingBehavior, InfinytecWebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
          <crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="InfinytecWebService.InfinytecServices">
        <endpoint address=""
                  behaviorConfiguration="web"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="InfinytecWebService.IInfinytecServices" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And at least , the CORS

```
public class CORSEnablingBehavior : BehaviorExtensionElement, IEndpointBehavior

    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
            BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters){ }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime) { }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(
              new CORSHeaderInjectingMessageInspector()
            );
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) { }

        public override Type BehaviorType { get { return typeof(CORSEnablingBehavior); } }

        protected override object CreateBehavior() { return new CORSEnablingBehavior(); }

        private class CORSHeaderInjectingMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
        {
            public object AfterReceiveRequest(
              ref Message request,
              IClientChannel channel,
              InstanceContext instanceContext)
            {
                return null;
            }
            private static IDictionary<string, string> _headersToInject = new Dictionary<string, string>
          {
            { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" },
            { "Access-Control-Request-Method", "POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" },
            { "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,Content-Type" }
          };
            public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
            {
                var httpHeader = reply.Properties["httpResponse"] as HttpResponseMessageProperty;
                foreach (var item in _headersToInject)
                    httpHeader.Headers.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can you help me?

In advance, thanks! :)

[image: Network Tab]
[image: List of errors]

Comment: can you post a screen shot of your browser network tab. the browser is making two calls one using OPTIONS and the other using POST method . when your service receive request with OPTIONS method it should return the CORS info and end the request before it gets to the your api method . since the api only accepts POST it is failing to process OPTIONS request.

Comment: Added in the post, I 've also add the Console Tab.

Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following

- Define a another WebInvoke method with Method="OPTIONS"  , the method should return empty content , since your CORS behavior handler adds all pre-flight headers needed for your browser .
- Your CORS Extension should analyze the current request METHOD if it is OPTIONS it should short-circuit and return empty content with the pre-flight headers. If the method type is "GET"/"POST" it should let the request through to be processed by the endpoint.

The browser makes two request one to get pre-flight info using options and another for the actual api call .

the problem you are having is the first call by the browser Method=OPTIONS is being rejected by your endpoint. because it can only process POST.